# how to dynamically create dataframes with filtered column names

Tags: python, pandas

how to dynamically get column from dataset into individual dataframe. Example if my dataset contains id,name,age and address and I had create a list containing column names. if I pass the list to an for loop and it have check the column name in the list and column name in the dataframe if it matches then it have concat that into the empty dataframe created for it.

eg:

```
l =[age,address]

age = pd.Dataframe()
address = pd.DataFrame()

for i in l:
filtered = df[[i]]
```

into the respective dataframes

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
index  age   address   c
1      2   3   4
2      3   4   5
filtered = df[['age', 'address']]
```